# PHP can't use sessions or headers suddenly

Tags: php, html

I have a login for my website, and up until today it has been working fine. I was trying to log in to create a post, however it didn't work and outputted this to the error_log file:

```
[28-Mar-2014 14:54:10] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php:3) in /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php on line 8
[28-Mar-2014 14:54:10] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php:3) in /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php on line 8
[28-Mar-2014 14:54:10] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php:3) in /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php on line 30
```

The code in login.php is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<?php

include 'includes/conn.php';
include 'includes/hash.php';

session_start();

$msg = "";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password, Verified, Admin FROM Users WHERE Name=?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $user);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($hash, $ver, $admin);

    if($query){

            while($query->fetch()){

                if($ver == "T"){
                        if(validate_password($password, $hash)){
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                            $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
                            header("Location: /");
                        }else{
                            $msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
                        }
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Your account has not been verified, please check your email and do so now if you wish to continue.';
                }

            }

    }else{
        $msg = 'An error occurred when trying to log you in ( ' . $query->errno .' ): ' . $query->error;
    }

}

?>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>DiscFire Softworks - Login</title>

        <!--[if lte IE 10]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/ie-styles.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 11]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <style type="text/css">

            @import url('includes/styles.css');

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="body">

            <img src="images/header.jpg" />

            <div class="navbar">

                <?php

                    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Parent FROM pages ORDER BY ID asc");
                    $query->execute();
                    $query->bind_result($name, $parent);

                    while($query->fetch())
                    {
                        if($parent == "self")
                        {
                            echo '<form action="/"><input name="page" type="submit" value="' . $name . '" /></form>';
                        }
                    }

                ?>

            </div>

            <p style="margin-left: 90px;"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>

            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" style="width: 40%;" value="<?php echo $user; ?>"/>
                <br />
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 40%; margin-left: 2px;" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** Another problem, my doctype only works before the PHP code, however I can't use headers after an output... any solutions?

Comment: Try adding session_start(); before your includes?

Comment: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home8/encantoj/public_html/discfiresoftworks/login.php:3)

Comment: You can't put your doctype before `session_start()`.

Comment: Well, I tired that for just login.php, should I do it in everything?

Comment: @Slier I can never understand that sort of error

Comment: @StressedProgrammer that mean ur script already produce an output yet `session_start` should be call before any output

Comment: @Slier OK, That makes sense, although it didn't work after everyone told me to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<?php

include 'includes/conn.php';
include 'includes/hash.php';

$msg = "";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password, Verified, Admin FROM Users WHERE Name=?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $user);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($hash, $ver, $admin);

    if($query){

            while($query->fetch()){

                if($ver == "T"){
                        if(validate_password($password, $hash)){
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                            $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
                            header("Location: /");
                        }else{
                            $msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
                        }
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Your account has not been verified, please check your email and do so now if you wish to continue.';
                }

            }

    }else{
        $msg = 'An error occurred when trying to log you in ( ' . $query->errno .' ): ' . $query->error;
    }

}

?>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>DiscFire Softworks - Login</title>

        <!--[if lte IE 10]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/ie-styles.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 11]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <style type="text/css">

            @import url('includes/styles.css');

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="body">

            <img src="images/header.jpg" />

            <div class="navbar">

                <?php

                    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Parent FROM pages ORDER BY ID asc");
                    $query->execute();
                    $query->bind_result($name, $parent);

                    while($query->fetch())
                    {
                        if($parent == "self")
                        {
                            echo '<form action="/"><input name="page" type="submit" value="' . $name . '" /></form>';
                        }
                    }

                ?>

            </div>

            <p style="margin-left: 90px;"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>

            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" style="width: 40%;" value="<?php echo $user; ?>"/>
                <br />
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 40%; margin-left: 2px;" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Put `session_start()` at top of your script

Comment: Oh wait, now it works.... weird, after about 20 tries after moving the session_start() it worked.

Comment: @StressedProgrammer maybe u have space :) ...u cant even output a space

Comment: you might be able to help me with this, if I put my doctype after the php code, it doesn't work, but if I put it where you said it does, which means I can't use header(), thus breaking part of my website. Any fix?

Comment: @StressedProgrammer kindly open new question